# Application file tracing on the runtime

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm working on a software that I must add some new features on it. Its on Linux and runs on the terminal.

What I want to know is how can I find out all the files that being used when I run a certain command.

Note that The application is so large has a lot of files for different daemons. I'm concerned about one daemon and I want to know what files from the app are responsible about running this daemon.
Anyone have a clue about this ? 
Thanks

Comment: Check out the `strace` command.

Comment: If you're concerned about one single process .. You can simply `if pgrep -x "myprocess.sh" > /dev/null then` and then run a stack trace